# Handle change on different inputs

Tags: lightning-web-components

I know this might sound as a too simple question, but I have to ask.
I have this:

```
<template>
<lightning-card>
    <div if:true={pendingAction}>
        <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading"></lightning-spinner>
    </div>

    <lightning-input label="Titulo" placeholder={placeholder} value={title} onchange={handleOnChange}></lightning-input>
    <p>Actual: {currentTitle}</p>

    <lightning-input label="Precio" placeholder={placeholder} value={price}></lightning-input>
    <p>Actual: {currentPrice}</p>

    <lightning-input label="Stock" placeholder={placeholder} value={stock}></lightning-input>
    <p>Actual: $ {currentStock}</p>

    <lightning-input label="Estado" placeholder={placeholder} value={status}></lightning-input>
    <!-- <p>Actual: {status}</p> -->

    <lightning-input label="Envio Gratis" type="checkbox" checked={hasFreeShipping}></lightning-input>

    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
        <lightning-button onclick={exportValues} label="Enviar"></lightning-button>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
```

So, I want each input to change the values of individual properties (for instance, the one with the value "title" should change the value of the property title, etc etc). I thought putting the value attribute and binding it would do the trick, but it doesn't apparently. Do I really have to make as many handlers as i have inputs to assign the new values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data binding in LWC is one-way, from parent to child. However, you also don't need a unique handler per input. To use your example, we start by adding a name:

```
<template>
<lightning-card>
    <div if:true={pendingAction}>
        <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading"></lightning-spinner>
    </div>

    <lightning-input label="Titulo" placeholder={placeholder} name="title" value={title} onchange={handleOnChange}></lightning-input>
    <p>Actual: {currentTitle}</p>

    <lightning-input label="Precio" placeholder={placeholder} name="price" value={price} onchange={handleOnChange}></lightning-input>
    <p>Actual: {currentPrice}</p>

    <lightning-input label="Stock" placeholder={placeholder} name="stock" value={stock} onchange={handleOnChange}></lightning-input>
    <p>Actual: $ {currentStock}</p>

    <lightning-input label="Estado" placeholder={placeholder} name="status" value={status} onchange={handleOnChange}></lightning-input>
    <!-- <p>Actual: {status}</p> -->

    <lightning-input label="Envio Gratis" type="checkbox" name="hasFreeShipping" checked={hasFreeShipping} onchange={handleOnChange}></lightning-input>

    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
        <lightning-button onclick={exportValues} label="Enviar"></lightning-button>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

Then, in your handler, we can use that:

```
handleOnChange(event) {
  if(event.target.type === 'checkbox') {
    this[event.target.name] = event.target.checked;
  } else { 
    this[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
  }
}
```

You do need to handle select lists and such differently, if you have them, but this allows you to have the same method for all of your handlers.

Comment: Hey, thanks! So, when you do this[event.target.name] you are calling the property with the name defined in the input right? That's nice, I didn't know that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @joacoiudica Yes, in JavaScript, we can access properties dynamically, just like array indexes, by using the `[key]` notation.

Comment: Hi I am facing similar kind of issue. I am getting taregt name as undefined.